# Why fragment transaction always starts from Fragment A?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions

I have four fragments and one activiy, suppose fa, fb, fc and fd. I would like to make a simple transaction between a->b->c->d. When i use for example:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fB);
transaction.commit();
```

it makes a transaction from a to b, but if a repeat the code but now to fC:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fC);
transaction.commit();
```

now it makes a transaction from a to c. and i want b to c.

any ideas?

Comment: If you start the transaction in A, then it will go from A to whatever fragment you specify as the next fragment.

Comment: That's what i think, but the question is how to implement what i want..

Comment: If you want to go from B to C, then go to B first, and then to C.

Comment: That's what i suppose to be doing, but when i make a transaction from a to b, and then from b to c, it makes a transaction from a to c

Comment: How is the correct way in code, to go from A to B, and then, when i touch a button for example, to go from B to C. All the fragments are showing on the default fragment A container.